# getCodeBase() gives nullpointer in Java Applet

Tags: java, file, applet

I have created an applet to read some info from a file on the server. I try to access the file using the following code:

```
Properties Settings = new Properties();
settings.load(new URL(getDocumentBase(), "settings.ini")).openStream());
```

All of a sudden, the second line is giving me the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.applet.Applet.getDocumentBase(Unknown Source)
```

My applet is signed and I access it through my localhost.Why can't I use getDocumentBase anymore?

Btw, I am using Netbeans Web Start option to create the necessary files (jars, html, jnlp) and then move them to my IIS local server.

**SOLUTION**

I'm loading the ini file from within the jar now:

```
Properties Settings = new Properties();
URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/myapplet/settings.ini");
settings.load(url.openStream());
```

Comment: In which version of which JRE (vendor) does it fail to provide the code base & document base?  Has the HTML been [validated](http://validator.w3.org/)?  What is the content of the HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION

I'm loading the ini file from within the jar now:

```
Properties Settings = new Properties();
URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/myapplet/settings.ini");
settings.load(url.openStream());
```

Answer (score 1):

At first glance I would expect:

```
new URL(getCodeBase(), "settings.ini")
```

as getCodeBase gives the directory URL, getDocumentBase gives the HTML URL.
That it worked previously is astonishing. Maybe the HTML URL ended with ?... and you read the HTML page?

Comment: Called the code in start(), *not* init()? Call **System.out.println(url.getPath())** and see it in the java console. Maybe the HTML got a meta with codebase, or the applet HTML is wrong. Good you found a pragmatic solution.

Comment: I don't know what you mean questioning why they'd work.  A quick test here shows bother work in applet viewer, as I'd expect  (I don't have a browser plug-in configured at the moment).